# How do I modify a column in an array to add a month and year to the day value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a budget workbook in Google Sheets and need to take a list of monthly expenses and apply dates to those so I can aggregate with other types of expenses (one-time, bi-weekly, etc).  The monthly expenses sheet is shown by 4 columns:  Name, amount, day (monthly day the expense is due), and account.  The list shows only one instance of each expense.

I want to take that array with the initial list and create 12 in-line copies on another sheet and modify each based on the month (e.g. modify first round of copies to add a "1/" + day + "/YY".

Some starting code with var names I'm using is below.  I've tried several iterations with different functions (map, copy, etc), but have not had luck.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

```
function Add_Month_and_Year() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    var orig = sheet.getActive().getSheetByName('Recurring -- Monthly');
    var modified = sheet.getActive().getSheetByName('Recurring -- Monthly (BUILD)');
    var originalArr = orig.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
```

Comment: Where is the month and year going to come from?

Comment: Month and year would either be static (say run 1, 2, 3 ... 12 for months, and then 2021 for year for now) .... later could do in-sequence so shows next month for next twelve months.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Add_Month_and_Year() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh= ss.getSheetByName('Recurring -- Monthly');
  const shsr=2;
  let vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let oA=vs.map((r,i)=>{
    let dt = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),r[2]);
    r[2]=dt;
    return r;
  });
  Logger.log(oA);
  ss.getSheetByName('Recurring -- Monthly (BUILD)').getRange(shsr,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```